# Generating XML Serialization Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have some code that uses XMLSerializer to serialize/deserialize back and forth between POCO objects and XML.  My objects are decorated with the usual XMLRoot, XMLElement, etc attributes.

I'm looking for ways to speed up the process and I came across the fact that during the process, .NET generates a temporary assembly with the types used for serialization, and that you can pre-generate this.  I used ANTS to look at how long this dynamic generation takes and it takes 2-3 seconds, so that's definitely a way to speed up the process.

The XML I'm working with is not XML that I generate.  Another process does it and I can't change that process.  The XML is not well formed.  There are no namespaces, and root names are duplicated between different XML snippets that correspond to distinct POCO objects.  So both objects have to be decorated with XmlRoot("XMLObj1") attributes.

I found out how I can generate the serialization assembly, but when I run the sgen tool, it complains about the fact that I'm generating two objects with the same root name.  It wants me to put namespaces in my XmlRoot attributes, which I can (and it solves the problem) but the XML I get doesn't have namespaces in it so I don't think this is going to serialize.  And obviously the .NET runtime can generate the serialization assembly as is, or I'd probably get a runtime exception.  So, does anybody have any suggestions on how to deal with this?  How can I generate the serialization assembly the same way the .net framework is?

Comment: I suppose you could run `sgen.exe` with the `/type:type` parameter, but you could only do that for one of the types, not both. What if you put both types in different assemblies?

Comment: An other option might be to create one type with `XmlRoot("XMLObj1")` that has all the properties of both your current types; merge them so to speak. You would have one class that can handle both kinds of files then.

Comment: The multiple assemblies idea is intriguing in it's simplicity.  Never really though of that.  How do you make the runtime aware of these assemblies anyway?

Comment: You don't. The runtime finds them using a naming convention.